# Retrieving Value from Actions Datatable - QTP

Tags: qtp

In QTP it is said that actions datatable are local and values in it could be accessed only the code in the specific actions (like value in Action1 datatable could accessed only by Action1 script), and thats why we have to use global sheet.

But I came across the below function which would take data from different actions table, like if data in Action1 data table and code in Action 2.

Could anyone calrify me if this is feasible and if yes why is it generalized that values in Action data table is local and only values in Global datasheet could be accessed from anywhere?

```
DataTable.Getsheet("Action1").GetParameter(A).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Local and global datasheets have a relationship to the current **Action** by default. You can issue these commands on the first line of your action, and you'll get values:

- DataTable.GlobalSheet.Name
- DataTable.LocalSheet.Name

However, HP does not prevent you from accessing any sheet you want: the mere presence of an **ImportSheet** function underscores the fact that you can utilize external tables if the 2 tables are not enough. Using another action's sheet is no different from using a sheet from an imported excel file.

[image]

You have a point and it does make sense to limit access to local datasheets only to the owning **Action**, just as how local variables are limited only to the function that defined them. But do remember that an Action's DataSheet is an entirely independent object. Its only irrevocable relationship is with its parent excel file. That's probably the reason why HP did not put such a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could do that, however, why would you want too? Would it not be easier to make one script and call your actions from it? That way, you could just reference what row of that actions datasheet you wanted to use.

For example..

RunAction "Action1 [Action1]","1-1"

RunAction "Action2 [Action2]","1-1"

That would seem considerably cleaner and less confusing to anyone else trying to work on your test script.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable("columnname","tabname") 
Will be accessible from anyware.

Example:
Struser = datatable("user","Global")
Equals
Struser = datatable("user",dtGlobalSheet)